java.lang.IllegalAccessError getting this error
package Selenium;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;

public class www {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub    
        System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "C://EdgeDriver.exe");    
        // Start Edge Session
        WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();    
        driver.get("https://google.com");    
        driver.quit();    
    }    
}

I'm getting the following error when I try to launch browser. its a unknown error. kindly need help
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.RetryRequest (in module org.seleniumhq.selenium.http) cannot access class dev.failsafe.function.CheckedFunction (in unnamed module @0x667a738) because module org.seleniumhq.selenium.http does not read unnamed module @0x667a738
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.http/org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.RetryRequest.<clinit>(RetryRequest.java:39)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.http/org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ClientConfig.<clinit>(ClientConfig.java:33)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.edge_driver/org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.<init>(EdgeDriver.java:56)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.edge_driver/org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.<init>(EdgeDriver.java:48)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.edge_driver/org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.<init>(EdgeDriver.java:44)
    at grdtyd/Selenium.www.main(www.java:14)


what version of Selenium are you using? This might be related: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/11069

Do you have a module-info.java in your project? Try removing it.

You have a module-info.java file which means you are using the Java Platform Module System (JPMS). Delete your module-info.java file (if needed you can recreate it later via right-click on project and Configure) or move the JAR containing the dev.failsafe.function.CheckedFunction class from the classpath to the modulepath and in module-info.java add the required requires ...; statement for that JAR.

Your code works on my machine. And the error message you're seeing, java.lang.IllegalAccessError typically occurs when there's an issue with the classpath or the modules in your Java project, check these things, especially pay attention to the line where you have a path defined System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "C://EdgeDriver.exe");

Keep the edgedriver.exe in some folder instead of in C: drive.  Script may be not having access to the drive directly.
